# Trying to apply Occlusion physics to an object

Tags: physics

I'm running v2.79.

I'm self taught, very new, and trying to learn everything about 3D modeling. One of the things I'd love to learn is Occlusion.

And I've watched plenty of videos on how to do it, but I'm unable to even find something remotely close in my own version of Blender. In the videos, the area (circled in the picture) is usually a drop-down menu which has the "Occlude" option.

Even the premade file that Blender has on their wiki for Occlude just opens just the default starting cube with nothing else.

Was this feature removed in newer versions??

[image]

Comment: Occlusion physics only exists in the Blender game engine not blender render or cycles. It's for preventing unnecessary rasterization in real time. Are you trying to make a game?

Comment: Ohh, that would make sense. Not a game, but I am learning to develop Snapchat filters, and one of their options is to have a "window" to another world. Which is basically just a tube with an Occlusion object wrapped around it, so it looks like its part of the ground (Augmented Reality)